# Bootstrap : change dynamically radio button color

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have bootstrap radio buttons :

```
<div class="custom-control custom-control-inline custom-radio">
            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input"....
```

I would like to change the color whenthe form is validated. I tried color, background-color, border, outline...nothing works.

tried to add the bootstrap btn-danger class...nope.. even the word important.

[image]

Is there a way to change the color of the button dynamically (meaning by adding a class with jquery addClass) ?

Comment: Please create a complete snippet with tool `[<>]`

Comment: sorry, dont know how to do that.

Comment: Just copy full code of one custom radio then edit your question and press tool button like my prev. comment. (fiddle)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
/* default state */
.custom-radio .custom-control-label::before {
    background-color: blue;  
}

/* checked state */
.custom-radio .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::before,
.custom-radio .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::after {
    background-color: red;  
    /* this background image SVG is just a white circle, you can replace it with any valid SVG code */
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-4 -4 8 8'%3E%3Ccircle r='3' fill='%23fff'/%3E%3C/svg%3E); 
    border-radius: 50%;
}

/* active state i.e. displayed while the mouse is being pressed down */
.custom-radio .custom-control-input:active ~ .custom-control-label::before {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ff0000; /* red color code */
}
    
/* the shadow; displayed while the element is in focus */
.custom-radio .custom-control-input:focus ~ .custom-control-label::before {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(255, 123, 255, 0.25); /* pink, 25% opacity */
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1">Red on click!</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you get the logic you can use it with your need or give more details about your code with validation for more asist

Comment: Your thing works because I have to click no? I want to change the color without clicking but when I add a class

Comment: use default state css for any color you want without click plus with click use checked state css

Comment: My question was : when I click on a button (not the radio, a normal button), it changes the color of the radio button. Can you do snippet for that ?

Comment: and combined those state css with @Junaid Shaikh answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Bootstrap styles overwrite your styles.

So you can have `!important` in css Style that element get your styles only.

for exapmle

```
input 
{
  backgorund-color : black !important;
}
```

Comment: even with the important word it does not change the original color of the button

Answer (score 0):

when your form validation is true, add `active` class on `custom-radio` class

```
 $(".custom-radio").addClass("active")
```

and put this css in your css

```
.custom-radio.active .custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-label::before {
    color: #fff;
    border-color: #df1895;      //desired color
    background-color: #df1895;  //desired color
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With some help from the others, I found the answer. You just have to add this css rule :

```
.active:checked~.custom-control-label::after {
    background-color:red;
}
```

after adding "active" class to your input.